# How to remove repeated characters in string javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I have a problem in my javascript code, what I need it's remove any repeated char in my string

```
let myString = "RReeeemmoovvvvvvee";
```

and required output that I need:

```
Remove
```

Comment: What if you had a word like `Pizza`?

Comment: *"I have a problem in my javascript code..."*: where is it? What is the problem?

Comment: `    var str = "RReeeemmoovvvvvvee";
    str = str.replaceAll(/(.)\1+/g,"$1");
    console.log(str)`;